# Does the concept of Longitude and Latitude finds explicit mention in the canonical texts?

Tags: scripture, history, astrology

Latitude and Longitude are the units that represent the coordinates at [geographic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system).

Our ancient knowledge of Jyotiṣha śhāstras based on the [pañcāṅga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam) and knowledge of relevant [Ephemeris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris),  require some good mathematical calculations to arrive at relevant planetary and "time-correction" based conclusions in kuṇḍalī making, etc.

**So the question is**, if the concept of Latitude and Longitude finds explicit mention in our canonical scriptures? Do we have any 'historical' references for an ancient "Vedic Ephemeris" for astrological calculations?

Specifically in reference to Jyotiṣha śhāstras, considering how vast of a time zone India spans, and thus, making a kuṇḍalī definitely requires appropriate methodologies for "time-correction", since [IST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) cannot be used for all places of births due to huge longitudinal differences.

Comment: Latitude and Longitude are sure there in Surya Siddhanta and Aryabhatta, Siddhanta Shiromani etc. Actually the Surya siddhanta etc are texts related to one of the 3 pillars of Jyotisha- the siddhanta part or mathematical jyotisha.